# How to SELECT DISTINCT on multiple cols AND select other colums in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'd like to select any distinct combos of columns a+b AND select column c

The sql is basically this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a, b), c
FROM mytable
```

Error returned: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `group by` instead:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM mytable
group by a, b;
```

`Distinct` works on all the columns, not just a few.  This formulation returns an arbitrary value of `c` from one of the rows.  More typically, you would choose a value, such as:

```
SELECT a, b, min(c)
FROM mytable
group by a, b;
```

Comment: How would i break ties when the group by returns multiple rows?

Comment: @gluzt . . . The `group by` will only return one value for each value pair of values for `a` and `b`.

Comment: ok - that does it. had a misconception about group by. thanks!